# Is there any way to avoid this query so I can order by a different parent on Rails 5.0.0.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following model setup in a Rails 5.0.0.1 app on Heroku with Postgres 9.5.5:

```
class Tape < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :numbers
  belongs_to :player
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tapes
  has_many :snapshots
end

class Number < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tape
  belongs_to :snapshot
end

class Snapshot < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :numbers, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :player
end

#I want to order @numbers by the created_at field of its other parent, Snapshot, not tape
@tape = Tape.includes(player: {snapshots: :numbers}).find 55
@numbers = Number.includes(snapshot: :player).where(players: {id: @tape.player_id}, tape_id: @tape.id).order('snapshots.created_at DESC')
```

It seems like I'm having to do extra SQL work simply to order @numbers by its parent Snapshot.

I tried `@tape.numbers.joins(:snapshot).order('snapshots.created_at DESC')` and I see a SQL query ending in something like '....ORDER BY "numbers"."id" ASC, snapshots.created_at DESC' which means Rails interprets this to mean I want to order by `numbers.id` as well - which I don't. I only want to order by snapshots.created_at.  Now a query like `@tape.numbers.joins...` will also be an extra SQL query. 2 questions:

1) what's the code I can write that will result in the least amount of SQL work? Or is what I have pretty much it?

2) Why does rails insert the extra `'....ORDER BY "numbers"."id"` clause in `@tape.numbers.joins(:snapshot).order('snapshots.created_at DESC')`?

Comment: Since a snapshot `belongs_to` tape, does that mean a tape `has_many` snapshots?  I wonder if adding that relationship to tape would make a difference?  Just throwing something out there cuz I'm not sure :D

Comment: Thanks for that - I corrected the typo, snapshot `belongs_to` player.